# Counting homomorphism ($S_3$,$\mathbb{Z}_6$)

Tags: group-theory, permutations

How can i count all homomorphisms on $\mathbb{Z_6}$ to the permutation group $S_3$? I know i have to use $f(e_{z_6})=e_{s_3}$ and Ker f must be a normal subgroup of $\mathbb{Z_6}$.

How can i determinate ALL homomorphisms?

Answer (score 1):

The domain group is cyclic with generator of order $6$. Fixing an element of order $6$, every homomorphism is completely determined by where this element goes. Where can it go? The order of the image has to divide $6$. Which elements of $S_3$ have order dividing $6$?

Answer (score 1):

The homomorphic image of a cyclic group is cyclic. Also, the homomorphism will be determined by the image of $1$.   Thus the image can be any three cycle or two cycle.  There are $2$ distinct three-cycles, and $3$ two-cycles.  That makes $6$, including the trivial one.

In sum, $1$ can go anywhere.  And there are six choices, the order of $S_3$.  Note that there can't be a surjective one.

This checks out in terms of normal subgroups/kernels of the homomorphism,  since $\Bbb Z_6$ has three nontrivial (normal) subgroups, and there are three possible homomorphic images, $\Bbb Z_2,\Bbb Z_3$ and $\{e\}$, by the first isomorphism theorem.

Answer (score 0):

So, that's what i found: $f_1:\bar{1}\rightarrow Id$,$f_2: \bar{1}\rightarrow \alpha$, $ f_3: \bar{1} \rightarrow \alpha^2$, $f_4: \bar{1} \rightarrow \beta$, $f_5: \bar{1} \rightarrow \alpha\beta$, $f_6: \bar{1} \rightarrow \alpha^2\beta$.